# ComboBox with rounded corner

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I am new to wpf and I wanted to change the ComboBox style to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxClC.png) However all I could do was to change the highlight color.

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}" Color="#FF374046" />
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#FF374046" />
</ComboBox.Resources>
```

If anyone could guide me to understanding how to create it I would be thankful.

Comment: That doesn't look like a combobox (IMO) as much as a listbox.  But you can check out using a `Border` with a `CornerRadius` to give it rounded corners.  Similar to this: http://geekswithblogs.net/cskardon/archive/2008/06/20/roundedbutton-button-style-wpf.aspx

Comment: You're going to have to make a custom style template for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a quick glance at http://www.wpfhelper.com/index.php/styles-in-wpf/combobox/15-combobox-style-in-wpf. As mentioned in the comments, you need to create your own custom style & template for the `ComboBox`, `ComboBoxItem` and `ComboBox ToggleButton`. Play around with the `CornerRadius` of the popup element, to start with.